# How to auto start my own app in windows env?

Tags: windows, load

I am developing an application, we have to deploy it on Windows Environment.
I hope Windows can auto load my App when the OS is started.

Can you give me some suggestion please?

Comment: It would be helpful to have some specifics as to what your application is trying to do and what requirements it has during its lifetime.

Comment: We develop one app, but the host is on Windows System, so we have to deploy it on windows. Except that, there are some other apps, so i worried that when OS restart, my app may be not started by manual, So I hope the Windows can auto load my app.

Comment: I see. What does your app do? Is it a user-mode application or does it need to be elevated and possibly operate as a service?

Comment: It a user mode application

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this:

1) You create a shortcut to your app in:

> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
> ```

If you want specific to a user, then change "All Users" to your particular username.

2) Another way is to add a registry entry in:

> HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run

3) Add an entry to Win.ini. Run msconfig.exe from start menu to see the various options.

For newbies who don't want to mess with their systems, the first method is usually preferred.